# WordPress custom fields not saved

Tags: php, wordpress

Not specialist in WordPress so don't beat me hard if this is something obvious,  but I have 2 websites running WP 5.2.4 with a completely different set of plugins and themes.

But both exhibit issue that when I add a custom field to the page and assign value to it - in Preview this field and value are reflected and picked up by them, but when I do UPDATE to publish the change it is not! Moreover, when I go back to the same page in Page Editor Custom Field is gone. And there are only 3 other custom fields ( I assume from the theme ), those values are staying.

What am I doing wrong?

```
WP 5.2.4, 
PHP 5.6.27, 
PHP max input variables 1000, 
cURL version    7.48.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1e
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try the ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) Plugin - [Wordpress Link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)

Hope this solves your issue.